# SQL Sumar valor de una fila en las demás filas agrupado con distintos campos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente resultado de una consulta muy extensa, colocaré solo los campos relevantes.

```
SERVICIO                                           TIPO                                               CANTIDAD    TOTAL       
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- 
                                                   LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                              2           6
                                                   MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.              2           6
Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)            LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                              13          24
Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)            MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.              13          24
Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)                 LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                              16          24
Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)                 MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.              16          24
```

Resulta que como se puede ver hay dos servicios en blanco con una cantidad y un total, esos valores son generales, lo que quiere decir es que deben sumarse en cada fila que tenga el mismo tipo quedando un resultado así:

```
    SERVICIO                                           TIPO                                               CANTIDAD    TOTAL       
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- 
Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)            LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                              15          30
Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)            MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.              15          30
Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)                 LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                              18          30
Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)                 MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.              18          30
```

Me podrían ayudar a resolverlo? Ahora da la casualidad que los números son parecido, en datos reales va a variar mucho el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente sólo tenías que corregir el JOIN de la solución de tu pregunta anterior.

```
WITH CTE(SERVICIO, TIPO, CANTIDAD, TOTAL) AS(
    SELECT NULL                                     , 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                ', 2 , 6  UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL                                     , 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 2 , 6  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)', 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                ', 13, 24 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)', 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 13, 24 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)     ', 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL                ', 16, 24 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)     ', 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 16, 24 
)
SELECT c.SERVICIO,
    c.TIPO,
    c.CANTIDAD + ct.CANTIDAD AS CANTIDAD,
    c.TOTAL + ct.TOTAL AS TOTAL
FROM CTE c
JOIN CTE ct ON c.TIPO = ct.TIPO
WHERE c.SERVICIO IS NOT NULL
AND ct.SERVICIO IS NULL
```

Comment: Tiene la idea, pero esto va a fallar si no hay exactamente una línea por cada _tipo_.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de un CTE para realizar el cálculo, en caso que haya más de una fila por cada *tipo*.

Luego, hacer un `left join` con el CTE, por aquello que hubiese algún *tipo* que no tenga un valor general. Para ese caso, he utilizado la función `coalesce` para evitar que el cálculo devuelva `null` en caso que no haya un valor general para esa fila.

```
with
Datos as (
          select 'Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)' Servicio, 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL' Tipo, 13 Cantidad, 24 Total
union all select 'Transporte Hormigón (General Velasquez)', 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 13, 24
union all select 'Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)', 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL', 16, 24
union all select 'Transporte Hormigón (San Bernardo)', 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 16, 24
union all select null, 'LABORAL Y PREVISIONAL', 2, 6
union all select null, 'MENSUALES PREVISIONALES PARA INFORME.', 2, 6
)
,
ValorGeneral as (
select Tipo, sum(Cantidad) Cantidad, sum(Total) Total
  from Datos
 where Servicio is null
 group by Tipo
)
select   a.Servicio
       , a.Tipo
       , a.Cantidad + coalesce(b.Cantidad, 0) Cantidad
       , a.Total + coalesce(b.Total, 0) Total
  from Datos a
       left join ValorGeneral b on b.Tipo = a.Tipo
 where a.Servicio is not null;
```